# How can I connect Time Capsule to mobile internet 4G LTE and share it with other devices connected to Time Capsule?

Tags: iphone, wifi, time-capsule, internet, 4g

I have a Time Capsule but no internet cable attached to it. But I have an iPhone with 4G and I need mobile internet to be shared with other devices connected to the Time Capsule Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Can you turn on the `Personal Hotspot` on your iPhone?